# É possível criar classes com dois construtores?

Tags: php

Estou a fazer uma classe minha de ligação a Base de Dados em PHP com recurso a API `mysqli_` e deparei-me com o facto de não conseguir colocar dois construtores na mesma classe.

A ideia é usar as constantes definidas previamente se não for passado nada como argumento.

É possível ter dois construtores na mesma classe em PHP?

```
define( 'DATA_BASE', 'db_name'   );
define( 'USER_NAME', 'user_name' );
define( 'PASSWORD' , 'password'  );
define( 'HOST'     , 'localhost' );

class MysqliDB
{    
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $database;
    private $host;

    public function __construct( $user, $password, $database, $host = 'localhost' )
    {
        $this->user     = $user;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->database = $database;
        $this->host     = $host;
    }

   public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user     = USER_NAME;
        $this->password = PASSWORD;
        $this->database = DATA_BASE;
        $this->host     = HOST;
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual é a intenção com isso? Usar as constantes se nada for passado? Você pode usar condicionais dentro do construtor.

Comment: A ideia é essa @bfavaretto. Eu sei que sim, mas não me pareceu muito ortodoxo...

Comment: É mais ortodoxo que tentar ter dois construtores, o PHP não permite esse tipo de overload.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vamos primeiro à solução do **problema**.

Você não precisa de dois construtores, precisa apenas fazer o que foi feito no último argumento do construtor:

```
class MysqliDB {

    public function __construct( $user = USER_NAME, $password = PASSWORD, $database = DATA_BASE, $host = HOST ) {}
}
```

E se o objeto for instanciado sem argumentos, os valores-padrão serão usados.

Porém, isso abre uma brecha para o caso a pessoa fazer isso:

```
new MysqliDB( null, 1234 );
```

Esperando estar mudando apenas a senha e mantendo o usuário. E é por isso que você precisa de um método que verifique a integridade dos dados antes de montar o objeto MySQL para ser usado no contexto da sua classe.

Existem várias formas de se fazer isso, mas as duas mais comuns são:

- Invocar um método logo no após as propriedades serem populadas para checar se tudo está indo bem:

  ```
  public function __construct( $user = USER_NAME, $password = PASSWORD, $database = DATA_BASE, $host = HOST )
      {
          $this->user     = $user;
          $this->password = $password;
          $this->database = $database;
          $this->host     = $host;

          $this -> checkIntegrity();
      }

     public function checkIntegrity()
      {
          if( empty( $this -> username ) ) {
              die( 'Usuário MySQL ausente' );
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Remover os argumentos nomeados do método e usar `func_get_args()`:

  ```
  class MysqliDB {

      public function __construct()
      {
          list( $user, $password, $database, $host ) = func_get_args();

          $this->user     = $user;
          $this->password = $password;
          $this->database = $database;
          $this->host     = $host;
      }
  }
  ```

O problema dessa abordagem é que `list()` é meio burro e caso `func_get_args()` retorne menos do que as quatro entradas exigidas por ele, vai dar erro de *offset*.

E é aí que você mata dois coelhos com uma cajadada só. Se você **somar** (não mesclar) outro array à `func_get_args()` com a exata quantidade de argumentos esperada por `list()`, caso algum argumento seja omitido no construtor, esse array supriria os *offsets* com algum valor padrão, no caso suas constantes:

```
list( $user, $password, $database, $host ) = func_get_args() + array( USER_NAME, PASSWORD, DATA_BASE, HOST );
```

Na minha opinião isso ainda não dispensaria um método de verificação de integridade mas é porque eu sou paranoico.

---

Agora respondendo **diretamente** sua pergunta: Sim, é possível haver dois **métodos** construtores, mas não dois **construtores de classe**. Eu explico:

O PHP4 também tinha Orientação a Objetos. Do jeitinho esquisito dele, mas tinha. Nessa versão os construtores de classe era métodos com o mesmo nome da classe:

```
class Foo {

    function Foo() {

        // No PHP4 esse método era o construtor
    }
}
```

Quando o PHP5 foi lançado e a Orientação a Objetos do PHP reescrita e aprimorada foi introduzido o método mágico `__construct()` para servir de construtor.

Por questões de retrocompatibilidade com scripts feitos no PHP4 durante esse período de introdução do novo modelo o PHP5 ainda aceitava um método de mesmo nome que a classe como construtor então sim, é possível ter algo como:

```
class Foo {

    function Foo() {

        echo __METHOD__, '<br />';
    }

    public function __construct() {

        echo __METHOD__, '<br />';
    }
}
```

Não sei ao certo em qual versão do PHP 5 que isso começou a ser "proibido". Entre aspas porque esse fragmento rodando no meu PHP 5.4.14 apenas disparar um *Strict Standards* dizendo que que não é possível redefinir um construtor já definido.

Comment: Segundo o [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) a partir da **5.3.3** o método com o mesmo nome da classe não é tratado como um construtor.

Comment: Para colocar código abaixo de lista precisa de 8 espaços. Se quiser quebrar a lista para poder fazer o código com 4, coloque um comment `<!-- br -->` no meio. Tá melhor explicado na seção de *Código* no [guia de formatação](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas).

Comment: Em sempre me enrolo quando coloco código embaixo de lista >.<