# PHP array de objetos sem acesso aos metodos get

Tags: php, array

Estou tentando acessar os *getters* que são referentes a um objeto, porém este objeto está em um array, e por maneira alguma se quer consigo acessá-los. Segue a classe DAO (onde está dando a bagunça e que estou fazendo teste) e a classe VO:

DAO:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1); 
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
define('CONFIG', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)). '/config'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('MODEL_VO', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)). '/model/vo'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
include(CONFIG . 'conexao.php');
include(MODEL_VO . 'prioridade.php');

Class PrioridadeDao{
    private $conexao;
    private $prioridadeObj;
    private $prioridadeArrayObj = array();

    public function __construct(){
        $this->conexao = new Conexao();
    }

    public function teste(){
        echo "teste";
    }


    public function selectAll(){
        if(!$this->conexao->conecta()){
            exit;
        } else {
            $result = pg_query($this->conexao->conecta(), "SELECT * FROM prioridade");
            while ($consulta = @pg_fetch_array($result)){
                $this->prioridadeObj = new Prioridade($consulta['id'], $consulta['nivel'], $consulta['nome']);
                $this->prioridadeArrayObj[] = $this->prioridadeObj;
            }

            #### Aqui onde a coisa ocorre, no cast aparentemente está certo não consigo é acessar as coisas após ele
            #### por isso usei o var_dump para ver o que tem na saida.

            $this->prioridadeArrayObj = (object) $this->prioridadeArrayObj;
            var_dump($this->prioridadeArrayObj);
            $this->conexao->encerra();
        }
    }
}
```

Model VO:

```
<?php
Class Prioridade{
    private $id;
    private $nivel;
    private $nome;

    //public function __construct(){

    //}

    public function __construct($id, $nivel, $nome){
        $this->setId($id);
        $this->setNivel($nivel);
        $this->setNome($nome);
    }

    #GETTERS AND SETTERS
    public function setId($id){
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function setNivel($nivel){
        $this->nivel = $nivel;
    }

    public function setNome($nome){
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNivel(){
        return $this->nivel;
    }

    public function getNome(){
        return $this->nome;
    }
}
```

Como estou fazendo em MVC quero utilizar de forma correta as interações entre as classe. (Se alguém tiver um tutorial legal de mvc PHP agradeço pois as referencias que tenho encontrado estão me deixando confuso). Estive muito tempo programando com Java(Desktop) e para acessar os métodos é super fácil, já no PHP estou tendo muitas dificuldades.

Uma outra dúvida, tem como eu fazer 2 métodos construtores em uma classe que nem é possível em Java? Ex: 
1 - public function __construct(){}
2 - public function __construct($param1, $param2){}

Agradeço desde já.

Se eu trocar o "var_dump" por "print_r" tenho o seguinte resultado: 

stdClass Object ( [0] => Prioridade Object ( [id:Prioridade:private] => 1 [nivel:Prioridade:private] => 1 [nome:Prioridade:private] => MUITO BAIXA ) [1] => Prioridade Object ( [id:Prioridade:private] => 2 [nivel:Prioridade:private] => 2 [nome:Prioridade:private] => BAIXA ) [2] => Prioridade Object ( [id:Prioridade:private] => 3 [nivel:Prioridade:private] => 3 [nome:Prioridade:private] => NORMAL ) [3] => Prioridade Object ( [id:Prioridade:private] => 4 [nivel:Prioridade:private] => 4 [nome:Prioridade:private] => ALTA ) [4] => Prioridade Object ( [id:Prioridade:private] => 5 [nivel:Prioridade:private] => 5 [nome:Prioridade:private] => MUITO ALTA ) )

Comment: E o que veio no var_dump? Tentou o print_r()? Retire o @ desta linha:  @pg_fetch_array($result)... para tratar os erros.

Comment: Não entendi a duvida :\

Comment: @AndréBaill editei o post para te mostrar o que aparece no print_r. A e tirando o @ não ocorre erro nenhum, ali ta tudo certo o que me indaga é na sequencia.

Comment: vc quer acessar um objeto dentro do array?

Comment: @rray sim quero acessar os métodos get deste objeto, na classe prioridade que postei tem os métodos get, eu quero através da DAO resgatar estes valores dos objetos através dos métodos GET, pois não quero que os atributos sejam públicos, para acessá-los diretamente.

Comment: Tentou de alguma maneira usar um foreach($var as $arr) pra acessar elas?

Comment: Pra que o cast pra object?

Comment: @AndréBaill não tentei não, até porque não sei como é a sequência disso. Ficaria algo como: $arr->getNome(); ??? ou tenho que criar uma nova variável para para receber esse valor? Nossa cara esse negócio de object em php é muito confuso :(

Comment: Não sei bem onde quer chegar... Mas eu tentaria usar foreach($this->prioridadeArrayObj as $objeto){ echo $objeto->campo; } - só não tenho certeza que irá funcionar no seu caso, não custa tentar! :)

Comment: @bfavaretto eu vi em um post para converter, achei que dizendo que o tipo era object conseguiria acessar os métodos de alguma forma. Mas na internet afora só consigo coisas com acesso direto nada com atributo private. Devo estar pesquisando errado só pode.

Comment: @AndréBaill tu sacou o que eu queria entender, eu tava mais perto do que esperava, não tinha achado algo que tivesse me ajudado (só piorado rsrs). Esse teu comentário anterior do foreach me ajudou muito, fiz um teste e dessa maneira e consegui acessar o método get, que busca o que eu preciso sem acessar diretamente o atributo do objeto, até porque este está como private. Vou postar como ficou o código.

Comment: Ótimo. Eu já tive esse problema muitas vezes e solucionei usando o foreach... Mas também tem a opção que o @rray postou, que é quase a minha idéia, só que organizada :) rsrs

Comment: Muito Obrigado @AndréBaill seu empenho e dedicação foram muito úteis na resolução do meu problema.

Comment: Por nada! A disposição.. Sempre que tiver dúvidas.. Abraço.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No método `selectAll()` não é necessário fazer um cast do array para object, a ideia é a mesma do java criar um array e depois iterar sobre ele, a diferença é que você tipar ele com o generics algo como `Lista<Prioridade>` e no php não, mas os objetos daquele tipos estão dentro do array.

```
$this->prioridadeArrayObj = (object) $this->prioridadeArrayObj;
```

Sugiro que retorne o array no final do método, dessa forma.

```
while ($consulta = pg_fetch_array($result)){
   $this->prioridadeObj = new Prioridade($consulta['id'], $consulta['nivel'], $consulta['nome']);
   $this->prioridadeArrayObj[] = $this->prioridadeObj;
}
$this->conexao->encerra();
return $this->prioridadeArrayObj;
```

Depois disso pegue o retorno de `selectAll()` e faça um foreach.

```
$dao = new PrioridadeDao();
$itens = $dao->selectAll();
foreach($itens as $item){
   $echo $item->getNivel() .' - '. $item->getNome();
}
```

> Uma outra dúvida, tem como eu fazer 2 métodos construtores em uma
>   classe que nem é possível em Java?> Ex:
>
> 1 - public function> __construct(){}
>
> 2 - public function __construct($param1, $param2){}

O PHP não suporta overload então não é possível ter vários construtores, entretanto é possível ter uma função/construtor com um número variável de argumentos.

No php5.6 você pode usar:

```
function funcao(...$param) {
```

Nas versões anteriores use a [função func_num_args](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php)

**Leitura recomendada**

[Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73530/para-que-serve-um-construtor)

[É possível criar classes com dois construtores?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37563/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-criar-classes-com-dois-construtores)

[How to access object properties with names like integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333016/how-to-access-object-properties-with-names-like-integers/10333200#10333200)

Comment: Ficou parecido com o que eu fiz, mas como fiz um teste direto no DAO não ficou aninhado deste jeito, mas a ideia foi a mesma. Agora eu entendi melhor. :D me sentindo feliz agora.

Comment: Ótimo, o @rray sempre dá uma força nos meus códigos também... a lógica foi a mesma, mas a resposta dele está perfeita! Mas que ótimo que funcionou..

Comment: Obrigado @rray pelo empenho e dedicação desprendidos. Só poderias me tirar a outra dúvida? Se consigo ter 2 métodos __construct na mesma classe? Um com argumento e outro sem igual no java?

Comment: @LuanGabrieldaCostaRodrigue, atualizei a resposta agora.

Comment: Certo estou precisando mesmo de umas boas leituras, eu tenho encontrado muita coisa antiga na internet que muitas vezes não tem me ajudado. Obrigado por mais essa resposta @rray , e sim, vou ler essas informações que você passou e melhorar. :D valeu cara, abraço, agora vou dormir se não amanhã não conseguirei ir para a entrevista de emprego rsrsrs.

Comment: @LuanGabrieldaCostaRodrigue, de uma olhada no [wiki do php](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) tem várias dicas e materias lá;

Comment: Sei que o Post é antigo , mas a resposta caiu como uma luva aqui para mim também.  Vlw

Comment: @HenriqueFelix que bom que foi útil :)