# Duas Funções __construct() no Mesmo Projeto

Tags: laravel

Eu não posso ter duas funções *__construct()* em meu projeto Laravel ?

Tem uma no Controller.php e queria montar um *__construct* em outro Controller.

Só me da erros de variáveis nas páginas...

Estou usando uma **middleware** no *__construct* e quero usar em um **controller**.

Eu tentei usar em uma função que abre a página, mas não deixa. Só deixa usar no *__construct*.

Comment: Não é possível ter dois construtores na mesma classe ou o overloading classico, tem outra forma de resolver esse 'problema' no php. [É possível criar classes com dois construtores?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37563/91)

Comment: Acho que sua pergunta poderia ser mais clara

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não seria simplesmente fazendo só isso?

```
class PaginaController extends Controller
{
       public function __construct()
       {
            // Faz alguma coisa diferente
            parent::__construct();
       }
}
```

Pelo que entendi da sua pergunta, você quer tem algo definido no construtor da classe Controller, porém quer adicionar uma  nova funcionalidade no construtor de um controller filho de `Controller`, mas não pode perder as definições de `Controller`.

No `PHP`,  `parent` significa que você está acessando o método da clase Pai.

Exemplo:

```
 class Pato {

         public function podeVoar() { return true; }

         public function podeAndar() { return true; }
 }

 class Patinho extends Pato {

     public $idade = 1;

     public function podeVoar() {
          if ($this->idade > 2) {
               return parent::podeVoar();
          }

          return false;
     }
 }
```

**Nota**: Lembrando que em PHP, os demais métodos podem ser sobrescritos, mas tem que ter a mesma assinatura do método original (os mesmos parâmetros). Porém o método `__construct` não possui essa restrição. Então, se quiser sobrescrever o `__construct` adicionando novos parâmetros, não há problemas.

Comment: Se não está clara, por quê respondeu ? Deu certo. Era isso mesmo. Valeu. Não queria deixar tudo que preciso no mesmo __construct do Controller principal.

Comment: @PeterParker não estava clara, mas eu adivinhei que fosse isso. Tenho empatia com problemas de outros programadores PHP..

Comment: E não vem não: Eu sei que você é o Zoom :D