# Classe com mais de um __construtor no PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Estava aqui estudando um pouco mais sobre construtores no `PHP`. E me deparei com umas dúvidas.

1 - É possível uma classe possuir mais de um construtor?

2 - Se sim, como saber qual deles será iniciado?

Comment: Se não me engano, php não possui overloading nativo, mas há meios de "simular" isso.

Comment: [Aqui](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/5350/php/simulando-sobrecarga-de-metodos-no-php/?trace=1519021197&source=single) mostra uma forma "alternativa" de simular o overloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na teoria não é possível uma classe ter mais de um construtor no PHP. Por ser uma linguagem dinâmica o *overloading* de métodos não casa muito bem.

O que existe no PHP são duas formas de se criar um construtor. Uma na forma do "método mágico" `__construct` e outra que foi introduzida bem no início da Orientação à Objetos no PHP 4, onde o construtor era o método com o mesmo nome da classe.

Exemplo:

```
<?php

class ExampleA {

    public function __construct(){
        echo 'Método Mágico' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function ExampleA(){
        echo 'Construtor descontinuado';
    }

}

class ExampleB {

    public function ExampleB(){
        echo 'Construtor descontinuado' . PHP_EOL;
    }

}


$eA = new ExampleA;  // Retorna 'Método Mágico'
$eB = new ExampleB;  // Retorna 'Construtor descontinuado'
```

Como pode ver nesse [exemplo no 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/r2shH), o PHP dará prioridade ao `__construct` e só executará o método com mesmo nome caso não exista um `__construct` na classe.

Vale lembrar que a segunda forma foi descontinuada no PHP 7 (sendo alertado na forma de um *warning*) e será removida no futuro. Logo, use a forma convencional (`__construct`) para não ter problemas no futuro.

Comment: Não tenho certeza se ele quer estender classes, todavia a pergunta da a entender algo semelhante a esta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37563/3635, me parece uma duplicata

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123459/101