# Construtores PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, construtor, sobrecarga

Não é possível criar 2 construtores para uma classe. Como faço para instanciar uma classe e para utilizar as funções da mesma sem precisar criar um novo objeto? No C#, por exemplo, eu utilizo um construtor vazio e ainda posso usar um com parâmetros.

Comment: Não sei se entendi direito sua pergunta mas você diz fazer polimorfismo?

Comment: [É possível criar classes com dois construtores?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37563/91) e [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/91)

Comment: Fechei porque a pergunta diz uma coisa, e era outra que o AP queria. Também poderia ser duplicata de uma que o rray postou. Talvez alguma dessas também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=__construct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O único jeito de usar os métodos de uma classe sem instancia-la é se os mesmos forem `static`. Exemplo:

```
class User 
{
    public static function create($data)
   {
     // code here
   }
}
```

E para usa-lo:

```
User::create($data);
```

De forma não estática:

```
class User
{
    public function create($data)
   {
     // code here
   }
}

$user = new User();

$user->create($data);
```

Comment: Posso estar enganado porque a pergunta não está tão clara, mas acho que não é isto que ele quer saber.

Comment: Era isso mesmo vlw

Answer (score 4):

Como PHP é uma linguagem dinâmica, a sobrecarga de métodos não é necessária. Programar em PHP como se programa em C# não faz sentido. mesmo assim quase todo mundo tem tentado fazer. Se é para programar como no C#, então usa o C#.

Criar mecanismos de contrato como os que o PHP disponibilizou em versões mais recentes não faz o menor sentido em linguagem dinâmica, por isso causa confusão nas pessoas.

A solução neste caso é criar um construtor com todos os parâmetros e internamente tratar os casos de parâmetros que não foram usados e estabelecer o que fazer. Algo que dá para fazer em C# como mecanismo de compilação, obviamente com limitações. Em PHP resolve-se me tempo de execução, então é mais flexível.

```
class Classe {
    pubclic function __construct($p1, $p2) {
        if (!isset($p2)) $p2 = 10;
        //inicialza o objeto aqui
    }
}
```

Outra possibilidade é criar um método estático que faça a construção, aí pode ter quantos quiser, cada um com um nome diferente, e pode escolher como serão os parâmetros de cada um e como eles constroem o objeto. Portanto você tem uma função na classe que não depende da instância que criará uma uma instância internamente e retornará esse objeto criado para seu código chamado.

Mas aí pra que existe construtor na linguagem? Pra que criar uma pseudo sobrecarga em uma linguagem que escolheu não ter isto?

```
class Classe {
    public static function create($par) {
        return new Classe($par, 10);
    }
    pubclic function __construct($p1, $p2) {
        //inicialza o objeto aqui
    }
}

$obj = Classe::create($data);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/Constructor3.php).

Comment: Entendi, estou estudando php a pouco tempo, vim do C# então estou tentando me adaptar